# setDT() is not adding additional columns

Tags: r, data.table

I am using setDT() to add additional columns to a data.table but

```
setDT(mydata)[, paste0('F2_E',2:30) := lapply(.SD, function(x) log(value/x)), .SDcols = 32:60][]
```

is not being added when you run this script:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
date = seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"),as.Date("2016-05-10"),"day")
value =seq(1,131,1)
mydata = data.frame (date, value)
mydata
setDT(mydata)[, paste0('F1',2:30) := lapply(2:30, function(x) rollmeanr(value, x, fill = rep(NA,x-1)) ),][]
setDT(mydata)[, paste0('F2',2:30) := lapply(2:30, function(x) rollapply(value,x,FUN="median",align="right",fill=NA))][]
setDT(mydata)[, paste0('F1_E',2:30) := lapply(.SD, function(x) log(value/x)     ), .SDcols = 3:31][]
setDT(mydata)[, paste0('F2_E',2:30) := lapply(.SD, function(x) log(value/x)), .SDcols = 32:60][]
rbind(colnames(mydata))


rbind(colnames(mydata))
     [,1]   [,2]    [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]  [,10] [,11]  [,12]  [,13]  [,14]  [,15]  [,16]  [,17]  [,18]  [,19]  [,20]  [,21]  [,22]  [,23]  [,24]  [,25]  [,26]  [,27] 
[1,] "date" "value" "F12" "F13" "F14" "F15" "F16" "F17" "F18" "F19" "F110" "F111" "F112" "F113" "F114" "F115" "F116" "F117" "F118" "F119" "F120" "F121" "F122" "F123" "F124" "F125" "F126"
     [,28]  [,29]  [,30]  [,31]  [,32] [,33] [,34] [,35] [,36] [,37] [,38] [,39] [,40]  [,41]  [,42]  [,43]  [,44]  [,45]  [,46]  [,47]  [,48]  [,49]  [,50]  [,51]  [,52]  [,53]  [,54] 
[1,] "F127" "F128" "F129" "F130" "F22" "F23" "F24" "F25" "F26" "F27" "F28" "F29" "F210" "F211" "F212" "F213" "F214" "F215" "F216" "F217" "F218" "F219" "F220" "F221" "F222" "F223" "F224"
     [,55]  [,56]  [,57]  [,58]  [,59]  [,60]  [,61]   [,62]   [,63]   [,64]   [,65]   [,66]   [,67]   [,68]   [,69]    [,70]    [,71]    [,72]    [,73]    [,74]    [,75]    [,76]    [,77]   
[1,] "F225" "F226" "F227" "F228" "F229" "F230" "F1_E2" "F1_E3" "F1_E4" "F1_E5" "F1_E6" "F1_E7" "F1_E8" "F1_E9" "F1_E10" "F1_E11" "F1_E12" "F1_E13" "F1_E14" "F1_E15" "F1_E16" "F1_E17" "F1_E18"
     [,78]    [,79]    [,80]    [,81]    [,82]    [,83]    [,84]    [,85]    [,86]    [,87]    [,88]    [,89]   
[1,] "F1_E19" "F1_E20" "F1_E21" "F1_E22" "F1_E23" "F1_E24" "F1_E25" "F1_E26" "F1_E27" "F1_E28" "F1_E29" "F1_E30"
```

You can see there are no F2_E2, F2_E3,etc... columns.

Why would those columns not be added?

Comment: I don't think you need to `setDT()` every time. Just do `setDT(mydata)` once and then use `mydata[, blah := blah, by=blah]` from then on. `mydata[, paste0('F2_E',2:30) := lapply(.SD, function(x) log(value/x)), .SDcols = 32:60]` works just fine for me.

Comment: @latemail it didn't work for me. What were the final dimensions for mydata after the four runs?

Comment: @PierreLafortune - `dim(mydata)` is `131 118`

Comment: I get `131 89` on `data.table_1.9.6`

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

Use `setDT(mydata)` once, and separately. Then do all your assignment statements.

Additionally, if you're going to add a lot of columns use the function `alloc.col()` to over-allocate more slots up-front until next release (v1.9.8). i.e.,

```
setDT(mydata)
truelength(mydata) # [1] 100
alloc.col(mydata, 1000L)
truelength(mydata) # [1] 1000
```

In the [current development version, v1.9.7](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki), we've increased the over-allocation to 1024, by default. So this should happen extremely rarely.

---

A quick and slightly detailed explanation:

This happens because data.table *over-allocates* column pointers during its creation, and the default *over-allocation* length is 100 columns. You can check this with `truelength()`. See `?truelength`.

```
require(data.table)
mydata = data.frame (x=1, y=2)
setDT(mydata)      ## convert to data.table by reference
length(mydata)     ## equals the columns assigned
# [1] 2
truelength(mydata) ## total number of column slots allocated
# [1] 100
```

Let's add 30 more columns the way you did.

```
setDT(mydata)[, paste0("z", 1:30) := 1L]
length(mydata)     ## [1] 32
truelength(mydata) ## [1] 100
```

And another 30.

```
setDT(mydata)[, paste0("z", 31:60) := 1L]
length(mydata)     ## [1] 62
truelength(mydata) ## [1] 100
```

And another 30.

```
setDT(mydata)[, paste0("z", 61:90) := 1L]
length(mydata)     ## [1] 92
truelength(mydata) ## [1] 100
```

Now, the next time we do this, we've to add 30 more columns, but we only have *8* more slots free. So we need to create another object with even more over-allocated slots, assign all columns currently in `mydata` to the new object, and finally assign it back to `mydata`. And this is handled internally and automatically so that the user doesn't have to keep track. So the next time we do:

```
setDT(mydata)[, paste0("z", 91:120) := 1L]
```

The function `[.data.table` realises it needs to over-allocate again, and does so, and the new columns get added to the new object. The issue is assigning the result from this new object back to `mydata` which is in the parent frame of `[.data.table`. And that is done through `assign()` statement, which only accepts a variable name as character input, and `setDT(mydata)` isn't. So the re-assignment step fails and therefore the over-allocation couldn't be reflected back to the original object. If you'd done `mydata[, paste0(..) := ...]` then the input object `mydata` is a *name*, and can be used to assign the over-allocated result back to the original object, and that's why the suggestion from @thelatemail would work.

If this is all too advanced, just upgrade to the devel version, and this'll all go away, and is very unlikely to happen (unless you'd want to have more than 1024 columns in your data.table).

---

I've filed [#1731](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1731) to remind us to come back to this and see if there are other ways to get around this case.

Comment: can you advise on what/where the devel version is?

Comment: @user3022875 see [Installation wiki page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the same issue that you are. We can try to ping the `data.table` experts to understand the sticking point. @latemail gets the desired output so it works for someone.

In the meantime, since you are running the same operation on the third and fourth calls, we can combine them into one to get the desired output:

```
mydata[, paste0(rep(c('F1_E', 'F2_E'),each=29), rep(2:30, 2)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) log(value/x)), .SDcols = 3:60][]

 dim(mydata)
[1] 131 118
```

**Edit**

Remove the square brackets and it will work. I'll scratch my head for awhile until I figure out why.

Comment: I also removed the `[]` at the end as well.

Comment: That's it. It works without the open close brackets at the end. Weird

Comment: I'm really surprised that that would be the solution.

Comment: I can't create a simple version that stuffs up, e.g. - `dat <- mtcars; setDT(dat); dat[, paste0("new",1:2) := lapply(.SD, sqrt), .SDcols=1:2][]` seems to work fine.

Comment: I'll ask Arun about it

Comment: I see dim returns 131 118 but when you do rbind(   colnames(mydata)   ) you DON'T see the column names. Any idea why?

Comment: I see all the names in my output. I can't verify what you are seeing